# Change z-order of elements in interface builder with visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I can not find anymore the feature to change the z- order of UI elements in storyboards with visual studio 2017. I think in previous versions I could right click on the view in document outliner or arrange the views per drag and drop to change z-order of view element. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, you can arrange your element's Z index by right clicking the element in **Document Outline** => Arrange.

If you are deploying on Windows, we can't drag or right click to change the Z index directly. However, the current two workarounds are:

1.Open the Storyboard file with **XML(Text)Editor**, then you can edit the order by moving up or down the source code.

2.Open the Storyboard file in Xcode, change the order, save the changes and then move it to your Visual Studio 2017.